# Is there an event fired on general HTTP requests (like ajaxStart event by ajax requests)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am searching for an event which does the same as the ajax correspondent:

```
$(document).bind("ajaxStart", function() {
 //do something
});
```

but for all kinds of requests, like:

```
$(document).bind("requestStart", function() {
 //do something
});
```

so it should be fired by "href links", changes in `window.location`, form submits and so on...

Is there any script or possibility which provide this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to find out when a page is being left (no matter how), you can use the non-standard [`beforeunload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) that is supported by all major browsers.